# .htaccess mod_rewrite > 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am using .htaccess.

My original link is:

```
http://example.com/CareerDays/index.php?u_type=admin
```

And I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
http://example.com/v/admin
```

The entire code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]*)$ /CareerDays/index.php?u_type=$1 [L]
```

And I always get

> "**500 Internal Server Error**"

Comment: There is nothing in the log about the internal server error :/

Answer (score 6):

On my hosting I needed add first line : `RewriteBase /` until then I get Internal server error too.

Comment: Didn't help :/. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 6):

When you put configuration directives in a .htaccess file, and you don't get the desired effect, there are a number of things that may be going wrong.

Most commonly, the problem is that AllowOverride **directive in httpd.conf file** is not set such that your configuration directives are being honored. Make sure that you don't have a AllowOverride None in effect for the file scope in question. A good test for this is to put garbage in your .htaccess file and reload the page. If a server error is not generated, then you almost certainly have AllowOverride None in effect.

If, on the other hand, you are getting server errors when trying to access documents, check your httpd error log. It will likely tell you that the directive used in your .htaccess file is not permitted.

> [Fri Sep 17 18:43:16 2010] [alert] [client 192.168.200.51]
>   /var/www/html/.htaccess: DirectoryIndex not allowed here

This will indicate either that you've used a directive that is never permitted in .htaccess files, or that you simply don't have AllowOverride set to a level sufficient for the directive you've used. Consult the documentation for that particular directive to determine which is the case.

Alternately, it may tell you that you had a syntax error in your usage of the directive itself.

> [Sat Aug 09 16:22:34 2008] [alert] [client 192.168.200.51]
>   /var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

In this case, the error message should be specific to the particular syntax error that you have committed.

**You must have AllowOverride set to 'All' or 'FileInfo' in httpd.conf file for having permissions of mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess file.**

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 1):

This RewriteRule would never match...

You have to place the .htaccess in the root directory, with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]*)$ CareerDays/index.php?u_type=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried... still 500 Internal Server Error :(

Comment: Is there still a Server Error, when you remove this code? Is mod_rewrite actually enabled?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled, and no, the error doesn't show without this code :/

Answer (score 1):

Check your ../apache/conf/httpd.conf and look for:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If the hash sign (#) appears as the first letter, remove it, save it and restart server.

Answer (score 0):

That .htaccess doesn't belong in CareerDays. If you write a request to a directory off of the root, the server FIRST checks if the directory exists, if it doesn't it will then give precedence to the ROOT .htaccess. It won't `think` to check an .htaccess in an unrelated directory.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've moved the .htaccess file in the root directory, but it still shows me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Then upload to the root folder in ASCII mode from your FTP client.

Answer (score 0):

500 Errors are often the result of file permission errors rather than anything else. Check the permissions on your .htaccess file.

The required permissions vary depending on the environment (I presume this is on Linux - shouldn't be a problem on Widows).

Comment: I've changed the permissions to 777, and nothing has changed. I have the same problem on Windows too.