# HTACCESS 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I dont know much PHP, but i had freelancer develop a site for me, but now once i uploaded it to my hosting i cant get it to work (database and everything is set up properly).
I am getting 500 Internal Server error when i try to access the domain, but i can access the site if i type /index.php after it.
Same thing on the categories on the site, error is shown once clicked on them.
Here is HTaccess code, and here is the site url : http://tinyurl.com/vvcheft

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.../index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can't do `RewriteCond $1`, `$1` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: 500 means "Something has gone wrong. You're the client. You don't need to know what.". Look in the server logs for the real error.

Comment: @ceejayoz What does that mean :D I really dont have any idea :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess mod\_rewrite > 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205456/htaccess-mod-rewrite-500-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to refer to $1 in your RewriteCond line where it is.  On line 2, remove the $1 of the code you posted above.  I believe this should work as you expect it to.  If it does not, please update and let me know.

Comment: Just did it, but same thing happens :\

Comment: I just saw this in error logs
[Mon Feb 11 09:25:32 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: If this is the case - there are additional rules in either this .htaccess file or another one.  You don't have any [NC] (NoCase) in what you posted.

Comment: It looks you are right, i just found another .htaccess file in the root of the hosting, with tons of stuff in it.Since 10 sites are hosted on this hosting, im scared to change anything :\

Answer (score 0):

Got it, its working perfectly, i replaced my htaccess file with this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```