# eror .htacces Codeigniter on webserver

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have code .htacces that familiar when you using Codeigniter like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But its not work. like this.
[image]
 When I delete this .htacces, the code running well. I have been check mod_rewrite on apache is enable. I'm confused, need help please

Comment: What are you trying to do with htaccess?

Comment: ya with htaccess show this error

Comment: Go check the server log files. (The error message already implied that you should do that.)

Comment: did u set default controller ?

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectname
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Note: projectname is your root folder name

Comment: rename your htaccess file and try ... then rename back to .htaccess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205456/htaccess-mod-rewrite-500-internal-server-error

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have mod_rewrite enabled, there is still a setting that can prevent .htaccess from working.

Check your **httpd.conf** file and make sure that in the directory settings that

```
AllowOverride None
```

is changed to

```
AllowOverride All
```

If you need more details than that, just ask! I've kept this very brief.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; // make it empty.
```